# Select a column from a list of matrices using a list of vectors

Tags: r, list, matrix, vector, subset

I want to select columns from a list of matrices of different dimension using a list of Boolean vectors that represent the columns of each matrix.

I have tried different `map` and `(s|l)apply` combinations, even classic `for` loops, but I can't manage to select the columns.

With this code, you can generate a list of matrices and Boolean vectors to experiment:

```
matrices <- list(matrix(c(7,8,9,10), nrow=1), matrix(c(7,8,7,9,7,10,8,9,8,10,9,10), nrow=2), matrix(c(7,8,9,7,8,10,7,9,10,8,9,10), nrow=3))
listOfColumns <- list(c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE), c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE), c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE))
```

As an example, having the list of matrices created with the above code:

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    7    8    9   10

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    7    7    7    8    8    9
[2,]    8    9   10    9   10   10

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    7    7    7    8
[2,]    8    8    9    9
[3,]    9   10   10   10
```

and the list of Boolean vectors:

```
[[1]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[3]]
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The result should be a list with a single element:

```
[[1]]
[1] 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your list contains matrices that you don't want to keep at all we can first create an index vector that selects only list elements of `listOfColumns` for which there is at least one `TRUE`

```
(idx <- sapply(listOfColumns, any))
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Next we use `Map` to subset the remaining matrices

```
Map(function(x, cols) x[, cols], x = matrices[idx], cols = listOfColumns[idx])
#[[1]]
#[1] 7 8 9
```

Thanks to @thelatemail for the helpful comment.

Comment: Perfect! If I understand correctly, you are selecting all rows `1:nrow(x)` for the columns in `listOfColumns[idx]`. It makes so much sense once you see it done. :)

Comment: @markus - you don't need to specify both rows and columns explicitly - just `x[,cols]` will do it.